# Condition Average row wise of a dataframe based on values from separate data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 data frames. I am looking to average the df_to_average row-wise if df_condition corresponding value is equal or larger than 40 percentile row-wise

For example in the first row of df_condition => A: 0.2 B: 0.5 C: 0.3, the 40 percentile value is 0.28. So for df_to_average first row should only average column B and C and exclude A. The average for row 1 = (2 + 3) /  2 = 2.5

```
df_to_average = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],columns=['A','B','C'])
```

[image]

```
df_condition = pd.DataFrame([[.2,.5,.3],[.5,.3,.4],[.3,.4,.5]],columns= 
['A','B','C'])
```

[image]

I tried replacing the values but the output is a list

```
df_results.apply(lambda x: np.where(x<=x.quantile(.40),None,x),axis=1).to_frame()
```

[image]

I able to do so if the condition is based on a fixed value and not a row-wise percentile value.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df_to_average.values*df_condition.applymap(lambda x: None if x <0.3 else 1).values)

df_1['Average'] = df_1.mean(axis=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that:

```
mask = df_condition.gt(df_condition.quantile(.4, axis=1), axis=0)
df_to_average["average"] = df_to_average[mask].mean(axis=1)
```

The output is:

```
   A  B  C  average
0  1  2  3      2.5
1  2  3  4      3.0
2  3  4  5      4.5
```